# How to put this one half note and three eighth notes concatenation in Guitar Pro 6?

Tags: notation, classical-guitar

I've seen this concatenation (sorry for not knowing the jargon) [image] a lot and the way I've been playing it was like playing four eighth notes but letting go of the first E note ever since it's plucked (as well as playing the other 3 notes, just naturally pluck and let go), which I think is what the half note is used for. What confuses me is that I couldn't find a way in my Guitar Pro 6 to make this notation and instead I put it like this: [image] so I'm not sure if they are really equivalent.

Comment: Have you tried putting two low E notes in a the same time? You already have the half note there, try putting an eighth note low E at the beginning of the measure also. I don't know Guitar Pro but that's what I would try.

Comment: No, I can't add eighth note low E to it for it doesn't let me do so. I've tried editing on different voices, but it just simply doesn't let me do it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's possible to create something like this o gp, although it is not very readable. If you want you can make different tracks on the same instrument with `cmd + n` (I think is `ctrl + n` on other OS) where `n` is a number.
BTW the first image means "play the E and when 2/4 have passed play B, G, B" and the second means "play the E and when 1/8 is passed play B,G,B while the E is sill ringing". 
Because of this I'm not so sure of what you want.

Comment: I asked the same question on http://www.classicalguitardelcamp.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=99974&p=1065005#p1065005 and they told me these two notation are identical, both of which mean "play the E and when 1/8 is passed play B,G,B while the E is sill ringing". (Images on the linked site somehow got lost, but the first and second pictures are the same as here.)

Comment: @JichengHuang I'm no so sure.. because in the first image all the notes are connected (forming one melody) but in the second they are separated (forming two melodies). IMO, for what I have studied, these are two different things. Maybe I'm wrong but I have to check

Answer (score 0):

Your second example makes sense, and there's no need for the numbers, as the rest in the top voice shows proper timing. I've seen this sort of thing, for guitar specifically, just as four quavers. Usually a player who knows what he's doing will let the 'bass' note ring anyway. It sounds better. Did have a student from another teacher who had taught him to cut off that bass note, so played exactly as 4 quavers, just as written. It sounded awful!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found how to prevent the numbers from showing in Guitar Pro though. But my problem is actually how to put the form of the first picture in the software for I can only make it like the second picture now. Would the second look unprofessional?

Comment: If you can figure out how to suppress the tuplet bracket, not at all. It is, in fact, the standard notation for this kind of thing.